# bazel, python rules, created files how to get them

Tags: python, bazel, bazel-rules

How can I access files that my python is creating?
so inside a python i got something like:

```
from pathlib import Path
p = Path('my_file.txt')
p.write_text('testing')
print("Testing done")
```

then when i do `bazel run my_file` i can see in terminal text that all went well and info from print, but when i am trying to find my_file.txt there is nothing. So what do i need to do with my rules to be able to access that file after bazel run is done?

Comment: At the top of your program put `import os`. Change your `print()` call to `print("Testing done in", os.getcwd())`. Then look for your file in the folder that call shows you. I think you are looking for the file where it isn't.

Comment: @BoarGules like expected, it's inside bazel cashe folder which after script is done is cleared and changing cwd is not an option for me :)

Comment: Then put an explicit path such as r'c:\path\to\my_file.txt'. If the file has to be in the bazel folder then write it out twice,  once to each location.

Comment: i don't have an access to any other path since it's inside a docker so i cannot access my workspace :( that's why changing cwd for /workspace is not an option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at that [script](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_python/blob/929d5a13d4eb1b930086d9353fc6f2d6ad306e43/python/pip_install/pip_compile.py#L44): you can use the `BUILD_WORKING_DIRECTORY` env variable to create a path to the file in a working directory

Answer (score 1):

It might help if you can give some more details:

1. How is that python code being run? Is it being run as an action?
2. What is the `my_file` target?
3. You mention that you have some rules. Are these Starlark rules that you wrote?

But to answer directly: When a binary is run with `bazel run`, it's executed in a "runfiles tree" that contains symlinks of all the dependencies of the binary. So your file will be put in the binary's runfiles directory.

`my_program.py`:

```
import os
from pathlib import Path

print("current working directory: " + os.getcwd())

p = Path('my_file.txt')
p.write_text('testing')
print("Testing done")
```

`BUILD`:

```
py_binary(
  name = "my_program",
  srcs = ["my_program.py"],
)
```

```
$ bazel run my_program
INFO: Analyzed target //:my_program (18 packages loaded, 90 targets configured).
INFO: Found 1 target...
Target //:my_program up-to-date:
  bazel-bin/my_program
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.226s, Critical Path: 0.01s
INFO: 5 processes: 5 internal.
INFO: Build completed successfully, 5 total actions
INFO: Build completed successfully, 5 total actions
current working directory: /home/ahumesky/.cache/bazel/_bazel_ahumesky/5123c9882cdbb6c5e34f583431173549/execroot/__main__/bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/my_program.runfiles/__main__
Testing done

$ ls /home/ahumesky/.cache/bazel/_bazel_ahumesky/5123c9882cdbb6c5e34f583431173549/execroot/__main__/bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/my_program.runfiles/__main__
external  my_file.txt  my_program  my_program.py

$ cat /home/ahumesky/.cache/bazel/_bazel_ahumesky/5123c9882cdbb6c5e34f583431173549/execroot/__main__/bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/my_program.runfiles/__main__/my_file.txt 
testing
```

If possible, it might be better if you pass the output file path to the program as an argument, so that the file is at some known location:

```
import sys
from pathlib import Path

p = Path(sys.argv[1])
p.write_text('testing')
print("Testing done")
```

```
$ bazel run my_program -- /tmp/output.txt
INFO: Analyzed target //:my_program (0 packages loaded, 0 targets configured).
INFO: Found 1 target...
Target //:my_program up-to-date:
  bazel-bin/my_program
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.040s, Critical Path: 0.00s
INFO: 1 process: 1 internal.
INFO: Build completed successfully, 1 total action
INFO: Build completed successfully, 1 total action
Testing done

$ cat /tmp/output.txt
testing
```

Alternatively, if you run the program directly, then the file will be in the current working directory:

```
$ bazel build my_program
INFO: Analyzed target //:my_program (18 packages loaded, 90 targets configured).
INFO: Found 1 target...
Target //:my_program up-to-date:
  bazel-bin/my_program
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.219s, Critical Path: 0.01s
INFO: 5 processes: 5 internal.
INFO: Build completed successfully, 5 total actions

$ bazel-bin/my_program
current working directory: /home/ahumesky/test
Testing done

$ cat my_file.txt
testing
```

Answer (score 0):

`write_text()` returns the number of characters written to the text file, maybe you can check for that. Or, try `print(p.read_text())`

Comment: It's inside bazel's cache so that's not the case ;)